# How much time would it take for an immortal being to get bored?

Tags: humans, time

This man has a curse: not even being completely demolecularized would help, he just will get back togheter like nothing happened.

He has acces to tons of resources, so he can do everything he wants in our society and travel wherever he wants.

So, without the possibility of killing himself, how much time would it take to him to have done pretty much anything possible so many times that he no longer finds it interesting?

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Bowerick_Wowbagger Also: this is entirely opinon-based.

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors yeah, it is, but if someone has the time to do some math and just vaguely calculate the minimum amount of time that sounds right i would be very thankfull

Comment: maybe till the time ,he finds who created the creator of his world..

Comment: @JackIta Why not do it yourself? You need to hand-wave it because a) this is entirely dependent on the individual itself. Some handle boredom well, some are very creative in finding things to do, some **like** having a "boring" existence. b) the psychology of any individual blessed/afflicted/cursed by immortality will **change**. Our individual relationship with our mortality is very much part of what shapes us as persons. And since we have no immortal person to ask about their attitudes towards their immortality, there is no place to start in reality. So: you are left with hand-waving.

Comment: If he has a normal human brain, perhaps forever. He just needs to have enough hobbies that he forgets about having tried the old ones while he's doing the new ones.

Comment: Can't resist to post an XKCD reference: https://xkcd.com/505/

Comment: I don't think it would get boring. People have the ability to do their own thinking independently of the past. A lot of my past memories are scattered throughout my brain and slow to reconstruct and so I continue being able to do my own thinking independently. The brain is not hard wired. I have awareness of what's going on. Once when I was in a subway train, it was slowly moving at about a decimeter per second while stopped at a station with the doors open. If I were truly hardwired, I would have been like I already knew that it wasn't going to happen so I'm blind to whether it actually

Comment: happened or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It depends on the goal in life of this person**

Reference : Phil Connors in *Groundhog Day*

Phil is everything you describe except he can't travel through space (you know, because of the blizzard) and time (he relives the same day over and over again). When he suicides he just wakes up in the morning. So OK for immortality.

Phil is stuck in Punxsutawney in U.S.A. so he has access to all T.V. channels in 1993 (documentary,...) and apparently a lot of people in this town are specialized. So OK for massive resources and let's handwave he has access to modern day Internet, or at least a library in town.

At the end of the movie, we can see he masters a LOT of techniques :

- piano
- car reparation
- medecine
- stunt drive
- ice sculpture
- culture through *Jeopardy!*

According to some studies, he might have been stuck [34 years](http://whatculture.com/film/just-how-many-days-does-bill-murray-really-spend-stuck-reliving-groundhog-day) to master all this. Getting back to the goal in life, he is doing all this to seduce Rita, and of course it pays and ends the loop.

So Phil's goal is seduction, but other persons could have other motives :

- science knowledge as other answers suggest
- philosophy and religious matters
- death provocation (stunts, glutony,...)

Laziness shouldn't be a motive since after a few years, you might say "hey I have to do something" and go through the list above.

So you could have some levels of boredom, but there would be always something to do, even when time-stuck.

Comment: Sci-fi has a [cannon answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6334/how-long-was-bill-murrays-character-phil-davis-supposed-to-be-in-a-time-loop) to how long it lasted from the screen writer himself.

Answer (score 4):

For me, **never** as long as the current rate of inventions etc. keeps going.
Especially when space travel will be a thing. You could get your own spaceship and explore star systems far away. 
I'd probably do something like that.
Favorite things to do would probably be:

- Find new (preferably survivable) planets
- Make a maaaassive building entirely in my design.
- Talk to an AI
- Go on an interstellar trip.
- Get a bionic eye.
- Go skydiving without a parachute*.
- Create a starship that is massive
- Become a scientist/engineer
- See what is on the other side of a black hole. (indestructible ey :P)
- I think as soon as space travel is open and you would be unable to die from starvation you could simply fly to every planet and have a look.

Comment: you are right, but to make something like that you would have to wait really a lot of time, cause almost everything in that list is something that we can't even imagine to do

Comment: AI will be smarter than us in approximately 45 years, Jumping out of a plane you can do and scientist you can do. You can also build a massive building by yourself which will take a lot of time to do even with equipment.

Answer (score 3):

He will never gets bored when he engages in a long-term never-ending activity.

Possible choices are:

- Science (already mentioned by Gistiv)
- Religion: Live as a monk in a monastery with very strict rules, performing religious rituals every day
- Complex games. Devote yourself to the determination of the optimal play in a game like Chess, or Go (to make it more far-reaching, try Go on a 361 times 361 board)
- Undertake an impossible task like [Sisphus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus)

Comment: i think that if someone does something like that for days, months, years, decades, centuries, at some point he would eventually be fed up with it

Comment: @JackIta and then they can simply pick the next point on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Most likley for me, **not even a normal humans lifespan**. You got 365 day per year to do something great and exciting, which means 14600 possibilitys in 40 years(what is only half a lifespan) which is really a lot even if you'll do some of the activities/visits for multiple days. The day will come when you have done everything humanly possible at least once. From this day on you won't have a aim in life which will lead to a major depression or something similar.

Another depressive influence will be the death of all your family and friends until you are all on your own.(I know this is really a vague statement and there are a lot of points to consider but I personally can't imagine building up a lot of new good friendships somehow, for various reasons)

**Solution:**
In my eyes, the only way to get rid of this great bordem is to be/get a scientist(best would be a physicist I guess) because there are many innovations, discoveries and progressions that will turn to new targets what will drive you.